# How to send link directly to a local server file through gmail

Tags: hyperlink, shortcut, afp

Often via gmail I am sent an link to the location of a file on the company server, ie

afp://Client/Somename/Someothername/Bla/Bla/Bla/Hereisthefile.file
or
file:///Volumes/Client/Somename/Someothername/Bla/Bla/Bla/Hereisthefile.file

Sometimes this name is so long that it literally takes a minute to navigate to the folder. Is there a way, or a widget or software that would allow me to either click on the link, cut an past the link, so that I can navigate directly to the path? I know that gmail [forbids](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/XRZYPhTazck) this directly in an email, but perhaps there is a work around?

Answer (score 0):

In OSX:

1. Triple-click the entire path to select it (not just the blue part)
2. Press command c to copy the link
3. Click anywhere on the desktop or make sure you switch to Finder
4. Press command k
5. Paste the link into the Server Address box
6. Press connect or enter and arrive at the folder destination.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Space Age Crystal's suggestion will work for your afp (and smb) links, but it won't work for file links.

For file links, substitute these last three steps:

4. Press Shift-Command-G: Shift-⌘-G
5. Paste the link into the Go to the Folder box
6. Press Go (or press the return or enter key) to arrive at the folder destination.